# css position:fixed not working in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div which position is fixed, within that i have a div with position absolute....

There is absolute positioned div is working..... But position:fixed is not working in ie........

Hope you understand...

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="cont_left">
    <div style="position:relative">
    <div id="nav">
    <div style="display: block;" class="menu"> <a href="#">
            about
            </a>
        </div>
    <div style="display: block;" class="menu"> <a href="#">
            services
            </a>
        </div>

        ......

        </div>
    </div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.cont_left{
    width:164px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    position:fixed;
}

#nav{
    width:164px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:58px 0 46px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: IE6 I presume? IE7 implements `position:fixed` correctly. IE6 doesn't understand position:relative. Reverts to position:static

Comment: i have heard from almost of sites that some project have a problem if use IE..i'm use FF to resolve my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this: http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<!doctype html>` to the top of your html

Answer (score -2):

If you use XHTML instead of HTML then position:fixed is definitely work.
On starting of your HTML page you have to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```